# Postgresql database with DNS records: how to mass-increase serial

Tags: sql, postgresql, dns

I am using PDNS with a Postgresql backend. I have multiple zones and each SOA record looks somewhat like this:

```
pdns=# SELECT content FROM records WHERE type = 'SOA';
ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 2014031201 14400 1800 604800 3600
ns1.otherzone.tld. hostmaster.otherzone.tld. 2014022403 14400 1800 604800 3600
...
```

How can I mass-update the serial-numbers? I'd like to learn both how increase them by one, or how to set them to something specific like, for today would be `2014032800`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems poorly modeled to me - or rather, they've denormalized the data for efficient querying at the price of making it really hard to manipulate in SQL.

You'll need to:

- Match and extract the SOA
- Increment it
- Reconstruct the original string form

As spaces aren't allowed in domain names, you can get away with using pattern matching for this, like `string_to_array`, `regexp_split_to_table`, etc.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_soa(text) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT
  array_to_string(
    array_cat(
      part[1:2],
      array_cat(
        ARRAY[(part[3]::integer + 1)::text],
        part[4:7]
      )
    ),
    ' '
  )
FROM (
  SELECT string_to_array($1, ' ')
) soa_parts(part)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```